# Using templates to set whether class members are const

Tags: c++, templates, c++17

I have a templated class and I'd like to almost toggle whether things within it are const based on the template type.

pseudocode:

```
template<bool isConst>
Class ConstableClass
{
public:
    // if isConst == true make this method const
    void DoSomething() "const";

    // if isConst == true make the returned smartpointer type const method const
    std::unique_ptr<"const" int> operator->() "const";

private:
    // if isConst == true add const at the start of the next line
    "const" int foo;
}
```

Is this sort of thing possible?

Comment: I'm working in C++17

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110082/adding-a-const-qualifier-to-a-member-function

Comment: `std::is_const` with `SFINAE` is what you need, and maybe `std::remove_const` and `std::add_const` too.

Comment: @metablaster: No, that isn't what OP needs. Or rather, not those constructs in themselves.

Comment: I'm willing to be someone has submitted a paper to the C++ language standardization committee suggesting this feature. Just like we have noexcept(some-constexpr-expression-here), we could have const(some-constexpr-expression-here).

Comment: @einpoklum I believe there is a paper which propose a template parameter for the implied object parameter of member function, so we could have the same implementation for different  cv ref qualified member function. It would help in this case too as the specialization with the wrong constness could be disabled.

Answer (score 3):

With type-traits and SFINAE:

```
template <bool isConst>
class ConstableClass
{
public:
    template <bool C = isConst, typename = std::enable_if_t<C>>
    void DoSomething() const;

    template <bool C = isConst, typename = std::enable_if_t<!C>>
    void DoSomething();

    template <bool C = isConst, typename = std::enable_if_t<C>>
    std::unique_ptr<const int> operator->();

    template <bool C = isConst, typename = std::enable_if_t<!C>>
    std::unique_ptr<int> operator->();

private:
    std::conditional_t<isConst, const int, int> foo{};
};
```

With a specialization:

```
template <bool isConst>
class ConstableClass
{
public:
    void DoSomething() const;

    std::unique_ptr<const int> operator->() const;

protected:
    const int foo{};
};

template <>
class ConstableClass<false>
{
public:
    void DoSomething();

    std::unique_ptr<int> operator->();

protected:
    int foo{};
};
```

With constraints in [c++20](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b20):

```
template <bool isConst>
class ConstableClass
{
public:
    void DoSomething() const requires isConst;

    void DoSomething() requires not isConst;

    std::unique_ptr<const int> operator->() const requires isConst;

    std::unique_ptr<int> operator->() requires not isConst;

private:
    std::conditional_t<isConst, const int, int> foo{};
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The first use case is not possible. You can't make function modifiers conditional and based on some template. However, I imagine you are trying to do this because you don't want to copy&paste code between the `const` and regular version of a function. In that case, just write a `private` impl method which does the actual work and use it in the `cost` and non-`const` version of the class.

```cpp
private:
int& get_impl() const {...}
public:
const int& get() const {return get_impl();}
int& get() {return get_impl();}
```

The rest is possible and quite simple:

```cpp
std::unique_ptr<"const" int>
// we can do this by:
std::unique_ptr<std::conditional_t<isConst, const int, int>> ...

// this can be written more elegantly as
template <typename T, bool isConst>
using const_if_t = std::conditional_t<isConst, const T, T>;

std::unique_ptr<const_if_t<int, isConst>>;
```

Making member variables `const` conditionally would be pretty pointless because this already happens when you make a variable `const` anyways.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible the way you want to do it. While there is a way to manipulate member variable types and function return types, there is no way to add/remove const specifier to a method. This means you have to write 2 separate specializations of the class definition for the true and false values of the template parameter.

Comment: ... or two different overloads for the member functions.

Comment: yes, that's right, two overloads. Btw, this is often the case, for example, STL containers have end() and end() const, first one returning iterator, and second one returning const_iterator.

Answer (score 0):

> I have a templated class and I'd like to almost toggle whether things within it are const based on the template type. Is this sort of thing possible?

Yes, and I find specializations to be more readable (unless you have access to concepts). The example below shows, rather explicitly, the two cases.

```
template<bool isConst>
class ConstableClass;

template<>
class ConstableClass<false>
{
  int foo;
public:
  void DoSomething();
  std::unique_ptr<int> operator->();
};

template<>
class ConstableClass<true>
{
  int const foo;
public:
  ConstableClass()
    : foo{0} {} // example
  void DoSomething() const;
  std::unique_ptr<int const> operator->() const;
};
```

Keep in mind that you do need to add a constructor for the `true` case, as adding `const` to `foo` implicitly deletes it.