# How to declare a const and non-const operator overload in one declaration (templately)?

Tags: c++, methods, constants, function-declaration

**INTRO**

I am writing a class `stalker<Obj>` that holds inside a variable of type `Obj`. I want that `stalker<Obj>` to pretend that it is almost the same as `Obj` variable (from the user's perspective). However, we hardly know anything about `Obj`.

So, I try to achieve this by overloading all possible operators (except for literal ones) and I also overload cast operator for the other unexpected behavior. This creates a lot of code:

```
template <typename Obj>
class stalker {
  Obj obj;

 public:
  operator Obj&() {
    return obj;
  }

  template <typename Arg>
  decltype(auto) operator[](Arg&& arg) {
    return obj[std::forward<Arg>(arg)];
  }

  // and other 20+ overloads...
};
```

The first problem is that `Obj::operator[]` can be returning `void`. I do not want to duplicate my code. Here is how i solved it:

**EDIT: there is no need for this (see the discussion below)**

```
// useless invention
template <typename Arg>
decltype(auto) operator[](Arg&& arg) {
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<void, decltype(std::declval<Obj&>()[std::forward<Arg>(arg)])>) {
    obj[std::forward<Arg>(arg)];
  } else {
    return obj[std::forward<Arg>(arg)];
  }
}
```

This code already looks heavy (*do you know a simpler way?).*

**PROBLEM**

`stalker<Obj>` can be tagged as `const` or it has a `const` type: `stalker<const Obj>`. Then we need `const` versions of all our operators.

[image]

*How can we templately overload a `void`*/*`non-void` and `const`*/*`non-const` operators in **one** declaration **inside** a class?*

*Or is there a better way to achieve `stalker<Obj>` behaviour identical to `Obj`?*

**APPROACHES**

CPP Reference has: [non-duplicate code of both const & non-const versions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zQAIK.png) (help me to understand this).

Another website provides: https://www.cppstories.com/2020/11/share-code-const-nonconst.html/. However, `mutable` qualifier or `const_cast` are not a solution. I hardly understand the part with templates but it seems that in this way we are not pretending as `Obj` anymore (we need to pass `obj` in some function).

Comment: *"This code already looks heavy..."* I don't think so.

Comment: [Const function calling non const or vice versa (to avoid duplication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44755608/const-function-calling-non-const-or-vice-versa-to-avoid-duplication) and [How do I remove code duplication between similar const and non-const member functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/123758/how-do-i-remove-code-duplication-between-similar-const-and-non-const-member-func)

Comment: What if `Obj` does not have `operator[]()` defined ?

Comment: it will get an exception

Comment: User must know what method `Obj` has

Comment: About link: It is a good solution but still it creates a duplicate of fuction

Comment: @MilkyWay Nope, it won't throw an exception, it simply won't compile. But yes, one shall know what is available.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/10110082/4165552 - similar question, but without the solution that you want

Comment: Ok, but what about cppref saying? Can you explain why it provides const and non-const versions simultaneously?

Comment: Returning `void` is valid.

Comment: Which standard do you use? C++23 has *"deducing `this`"* to handle const/reference  Cartesian product overload.

Comment: indirectly, yes

Comment: Does this `this` somehow influence constness of the function?

Comment: You don't need to do anything about returning void, your first snippet already handles that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> The first problem is that Obj::operator[] can be returning void.

It is not a problem, returning `void` is valid.

```
template <typename Arg>
decltype(auto) operator[](Arg&& arg) { return obj[std::forward<Arg>(arg)]; }
```

is ok.

> How can we templately overload a void/non-void and const/non-const operators in one declaration inside a class?

As seen above, void/non-void is no problematic.
There are still const/volatile and reference cartesion product overloads though.

Before C++23, you have to write all of them.

Since C++23, there is ["deducing `this`"](https://wg21.link/P0847R7) which allows to write just

```
template <typename Self, typename Arg>
decltype(auto) foo(this Self&& self, Arg&& arg) {
    return std::forward<Self>(self).obj[std::forward<Arg>(arg)];
}
```

You might SFINAE your method and use same `noexcept` to mimic more the type:

```
template <typename Self, typename Arg>
auto foo(this Self&& self, Arg&& arg)
noexcept(noexcept(std::forward<Self>(self).obj[std::forward<Arg>(arg)]))
-> decltype(std::forward<Self>(self).obj[std::forward<Arg>(arg)])
{
    return std::forward<Self>(self).obj[std::forward<Arg>(arg)];
}
```

Comment: Thank you for a detailed explanation. Can't wait for C++23)